# spf issue postfix

Tags: postfix, centos5, spf

`Received-SPF: none (domain of deens1.chickenkiller.com does not designate permitted sender hosts)`

`Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of root@deens1.chickenkiller.com designates 89.248.166.162 as permitted sender) client-ip=89.248.166.162;`

these are mail headers when i send email from my domain.I want to know why gmail is showing spf="pass" and why yahoo is showing it "none".

Comment: You don't have any SPF records specified for `deens1.chickenkiller.com`.  That's probably source of your confusion.

Comment: but why is gmail giving spf = pass

Comment: Because it's not explictly denied.

Comment: what do you mean by "explictly denied"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it has something to do with `best guess record` phrase in the `Received-SPF` header which probably indicates it (Gmail) hasn't seen any mails from this domain from any other IP address, which is to imply that it's not explicitly using `SPF` because there're no records, but trying to verify it from its records, unlike Yahoo! which is only using SPF record.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your response i created the spf records and now yahoo is showing "pass" in spf,the problem was that the spf records were not correct previously.